# dynamically determining polling frequency in mule

Tags: java, spring, mule, esb

I have been struggling to find a work around to be able to dynamically read the  polling frequency in mule flow. Currently I am reading that from a file using spring's Propertyplaceholder at the start up and value remains the same even if the fie is changed(as we all know)..

Since poll tag needs to be the first component in the flow, There is nothing much i could do to read the "live" file update.

Is there any way I could set the polling frequency dynamically  read from a file(without requiring restart)?

For Reference:

```
<spring:beans>
        <context:property-placeholder location="file:///C:/Users/test/config.properties" />
</spring:beans> 

 <flow name="querying-database-pollingFlow1" doc:name="querying-database-pollingFlow1">
         <poll doc:name="Poll3e3">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="${pollinginterval}"/>
            <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration1" doc:name="Perform a query in MySQL">
                <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[select empId,empName from employer where  status='active';]]></db:dynamic-query>
            </db:select>
         </poll>
....</flow>
```

Comment: BTW, I also tried to look at few things that listens to the file and fetches the value. 1) first of all, I do not know if thats the right way  2) I am not sure how to override the propertyplaceholder's map of properties values and update the new value (just read from the file)behind the scene so that mule can use the updated value to determine  polling frequency.

Comment: For Future readers, Here is the quick ANSWER: The accepted answer is to do Hot deployment although it is not a good idea in prod server.The other suggestion is to use JMX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no issue with  `<fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="${pollinginterval}"/>` as you can dynamically read polling frequency from a properties file ...

The only thing I am concern here is :- `<context:property-placeholder location="file:///C:/Users/test/config.properties" />`

Since you are reading from a properties file outside your classpath, better try with the following :-

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="file:C:/Users/test/config.properties" />
```

One more thing .. if you are using Spring beans for properties file use the following way :-

```
<spring:beans>  
    <spring:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
       <spring:property name="locations">
         <spring:list>
          <spring:value>file:C:/Users/test/config.properties</spring:value>
         </spring:list>
       </spring:property>
     </spring:bean>
 </spring:beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Can you explain How does it read the properties dynamically (meaning the file is updated after the app is started)? BTW, Actually I have the property file in my classpath, For clarity to the readers, I made it up.. I do not think that is  an issue.

Comment: If file is updated after the app starts then either you have to restart the server to pick the change or, if you don't want to restart the server but still want the app to read the updated value then you need to go for Mule hot deployment :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Hot+Deployment ... and if you have properties file in **classpath**, then you need to use `classpath:` instead of `file:`.  And regarding your `<fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="${pollinginterval}"/>` query .. it will read the value from properties file and I have tested it

Comment: <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="${pollinginterval}"/> query  is currently reading the property from file. there is no issue with that, I wanted to be able to read the property without restarting the server.  Hot deployment is a good idea. I did not think about it but was wondering if there is any (soft) way of listening the file change event and update the {pollinginterval} as and when the file is changed without requiring to restart the app. i know it is doable and there r apache commons file utils that notifies whenever the file is changed but i am not sure how to do that in mule

Comment: Hot deployment is a good Idea to let the server know about the change in properties file without restarting the server .. There are few ways of doing this hot deployment .. One way is after updating the properties file just make some change in your **mule config xml** file like adding comments or just putting a space between 2 tags ...and save it .. the Mule will automatically reload the configuration without restarting the server ... Now if you find the answer useful please accept it by clicking on Accept answer

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realized I could not do hot deployment as the file is updated by another flow(not manually). I could also touch the config file as part of the said flow but it seems dirty. I will wait for few more days before I accept the answer

Comment: Although hot deployment is not what i needed, I tried it by adding a space in mule config xml in standalone mule server , I am getting "illegalStateException:zip file is closed" exception.  I know hot deployment would work if we do it via IDE but that is not an ideal solution. I will try to do some research before accepting the answer. if you know any workaround, please do share

Comment: Yes... I am not sure about 3.6.0 but 3.5 and previous version standalone works

Comment: hot deployment fails too often due to permsize memory issue. Iam inclined towards not recommending hot deployment in prod

Answer (score 1):

The clean way using FixedFrequencyScheduler is not there. You could potentially go to the registry, fetch your flow by name, then get the MessageSource and cast it to FixedFrequencyScheduler set the new interval and stop-start, however if you take a look to the [code](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/polling/schedule/FixedFrequencyScheduler.java) you'll see there is no setter for it and reflexion it's just too dirty.

My first choice would probably be to leverage a [quartz](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Quartz+Connector) endpoint and then leverage the quartz abilities to expose the configuration throught [jmx/rmi](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/how-to-manage-quartz-remotely.html).

Comment: Jmx seems little complicated but yes logically doable. I was hoping mule should have some out of box solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely advise against using hot deploy to solve this problem especially if you need to change the frequency often. There is a risk that this will lead to problems with permgen running out of memory.

Instead you could use a flow with a quartz endpoint that fires at a relatively low frequency. Then add a filter that only lets through the message at the required frequency.

The filter can either watch a properties file for changes or expose attributes over JMX to allow you to change the frequency. Something like this.

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="frequencyFilter" class="FrequencyFilter" />
</spring:beans>

<flow name="trigger-polling-every-second" doc:name="trigger-polling-every-second">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint repeatInterval="1000" doc:name="Quartz" responseTimeout="10000" jobName="poll-trigger">
        <quartz:event-generator-job>
            <quartz:payload>Scheduled Trigger</quartz:payload>
        </quartz:event-generator-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <filter ref="frequencyFilter" />
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="query-database" />
</flow>

<flow name="query-database">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="query-database" />
    <db:select config-ref="databaseConfig" doc:name="Perform a query in database">
       <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[select empId,empName from employer where  status='active']]></db:dynamic-query>
    </db:select>
    <logger level="ERROR" message="#[payload]"/>
</flow>
```